# How to read Libre pro NFC sensor data from the flutter app is there any sdk which is provide by libre please guide me

Tags: flutter, nfc, android-sensors

i am trying to integrate Libre pro CGM nfc sensor with my flutter app but it seems like the sensor data which im recieving from the flutter package is encoded im not getting the glucose values

my question is there any other ways to read the CGM sensor data